# Can "so that" be used with a negative clause?

Tags: phrase-usage, syntax

There is an example sentence:

> "Turn in your report so that I can comment on it."

I call it as 'so that+ positive clause'

Here's the problem. Does 'so that+ negative clause' sentence make sense to you guys? For instance,

> "It keeps annoying me so that I can't focus on my report."

Is only " so that+ positive clause "right?

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences you gave in your question make sense although the use of *it* sounds strange when I would expect a *he* or *she*, even when referring to pets.

[So that](http://www.yourdictionary.com/so-that) sentences are used a lot to describe actions and reactions in the form of *so that I can/can't/will/won't*...

When using *so that* you are describing an action you or someone else is taking in order for a certain action to occur.

Examples are

> I wrote the appointment in my diary **so that** I won't forget it.
>
> He keeps the door locked **so that** I can't go out.

Another way of saying these sentences would be

> **So that** I won't forget it, I wrote the appointment in my diary.
>
> **So that** I can't go out, he keeps the door locked.

These examples are actions to ensure a particular reaction and there are other examples of these sentences which are actions in the hope of a particular reaction...

> I went to university so that I stand a chance of landing a well paid job

Comment: I agree that the use of "it" sounds strange. I had to read the sentence multiple times to understand it and think about it in a way different than my first reading.

Comment: I didn't realize "it" sounded odd to you guys  Thank you anyways

Comment: *It* is not necessarily strange. It is natural assuming that the referent for which *it* stands is made clear: *The air conditioner is making that terrible noise again. It keeps annoying me so that I can't focus on my report.*